# emacs key bind search buffer to occur

Tags: emacs, elisp, find-occurrences

I like the option to do <kbd>C-s</kbd> <kbd>C-w</kbd> and then show all in a separate buffer by using <kbd>M-s o</kbd>, but I would really like to keybind the <kbd>M-s o</kbd> ('occur) such that I can type <kbd>C-s C-w  C-,</kbd> or similar-

I have tried the normal keybind:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-,") 'occur)
```

But it just do the normal occur, not the search buffer occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command that is bound to <kbd>M-s o</kbd> during an `isearch` isn't the default `occur` command, but a special version called `isearch-occur`, that automatically invoke `occur` on isearch hits.

You can bind this to the <kbd>C-o</kbd> (or <kbd>C-,</kbd> if you prefer) shortcut without overriding other commands using the `define-key` command with the `isearch-mode-map`:

```
(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "C-o") 'isearch-occur)
```

In this way you can use the sequence <kbd>C-s</kbd><kbd>C-w</kbd><kbd>C-o</kbd>.

Comment: rasmus: Note that `C-h b` whilst isearching displays all isearch bindings. `C-h k` also works in this situation -- so `C-s C-h k M-s o` tells you about `isearch-occur`. (`C-h c` isn't bound to an isearch-variant, OTOH, which may be worth raising a bug report about).